# Transformação de Árvores

Tags: haskell

Considerando as estruturas:

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
data LTree a = Tip a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
data FTree a b = Leaf b | No a (FTree a b) (FTree a b)
```

Defina a função `splitFTree :: FTree a b -> (BTree a, LTree b)` que separa
uma árvore com informação nos nodos e nas folhas em duas árvores de tipos
diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para começar, é necessário ter em conta o seguinte:

1. **BTree -** É uma árvore na qual a informação é guardada nos Nodos, porém não é armazenada nas extremidades, visto que estas são do tipo **Empty**.
2. **LTree -** É uma árvore cujo informação é guardada unicamente nas suas extremidades.
3. **FTree -** É uma árvore "full", visto que tanto guarda a sua informação nos Nodos como nas suas extremidades.

Para a resolução deste exercício será necessário a utilização de **Tupling**. Primeiramente é recomendável analisar o que cada arvóre obtém nas suas extremidades, e fazer o respetivo **Pattern Matching**. De seguida é útil percorrer a árvore e registar a informação que equivale a cada árvore.

**Possível Resolução:**

```
splitFTree :: FTree a b -> (BTree a, LTree b)
splitFTree (Leaf b)   = (Empty,Tip b)
splitFTree (No a l r) = (Node a b1 b2, Fork l1 l2)
      where (b1,l1) = splitFTree l
            (b2,l2) = splitFTree r
```

Comment: Obrigado, é exatamente isso o que pretendia :)